# Does sbt/Scala have a "compatible release" similar to Bundler/pip >= or ~=?

Tags: scala, sbt, dependency-management

I'm used to using `~=` or `>=` to allow the package manager to upgrade to the latest compatible release.

Does sbt or Scala has anything similar to this?  I couldn't find it on their docs here: https://www.scala-sbt.org/1.x/docs/Library-Management.html

Bundler equivalent: https://bundler.io/gemfile.html
pip equivalent: https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/requirements-file-format/#example

Thank you for your time

Comment: AFAIK there is a way but nobody ever does that, we don't like projects that break randomly.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez sorry, was there a typo?: “there is a way” or “there is not a way”

Comment: There is a way: https://www.scala-sbt.org/1.x/docs/Library-Dependencies.html#Ivy+revisions - But again, I haven't seen any project _(open source or private)_ that does this, it is too fragile IMHO. We have things like **scala-steward** & **mergify** to help reduce the burden of upgrading dependencies.

Comment: Thanks for mentioning scala-steward and mergify.  Is this the mergify that you are referring to?: https://mergify.com/

Comment: if you'd like to write up your comment as an answer, I'll accept it.  thanks again for your help 

Comment: Yes, that is the mergify I meant. Also, I can't answer since it is only a link and an opinion. You may provide a good answer to your own question explaining in detail how that syntax works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just want to summarize the conversation in the comments:

There's a way to do it: https://ant.apache.org/ivy/history/2.3.0/ivyfile/dependency.html#revision

The syntax is:

```
Examples:
[1.0,2.0] matches all versions greater or equal to 1.0 and lower or equal to 2.0
[1.0,2.0[ matches all versions greater or equal to 1.0 and lower than 2.0
]1.0,2.0] matches all versions greater than 1.0 and lower or equal to 2.0
]1.0,2.0[ matches all versions greater than 1.0 and lower than 2.0
[1.0,) matches all versions greater or equal to 1.0
]1.0,) matches all versions greater than 1.0
(,2.0] matches all versions lower or equal to 2.0
(,2.0[ matches all versions lower than 2.0
```

It is not recommended and there are other tools to help with dependencies.

And even with my extremely brief exploration into the Scala/Java world, a lot of dependencies tend to be broken and backward compatibility seems to be more of an issue than my experience with Python and Ruby.  Even documentation seems to lead to broken dependencies.  It makes sense why these version ranges are typically not used in the Scala/Java world.  It could also very well be because of me being inexperienced in Scala/Java.

Hope that helps